# How to only include normal strings of text but not anything that contains a " .* "

Tags: regex, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

How would i get only strings out of a piece of text and not the piece of text if it contains a `.*`

so for example:

`foo` would return `foo`

`foo.test` would return nothing

`foo.blah` would also return nothing.

This is what I've got right now

`<from>/(.*(?<!.css|.js|.jsp|.gif|.jpg|.png))$</from>`

But All i need it instead of adding in all `.something` etc one that will do all if it contains a `.`

This is what it is used for:

A url rewriting api http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/
and it in in a .xml file if that is of any help?

this is my entire xml

```
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite
        PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 2.6//EN"
        "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite2.6.dtd">
<urlrewrite>

    <!--vote.jsp-->
    <rule>
        <from>/vote/(.*(?&lt;!.css|.js|.jsp|.gif|.jpg|.png))$</from>
        <to>/vote.jsp?id=$1</to>
    </rule>
    <!--server.jsp-->
    <rule>
        <from>/server/([0-9]+)</from>
        <to>/server.jsp?id=$1</to>
    </rule>

    <!--index.jsp-->
    <rule>
        <from>/(.*(?&lt;!.css|.js|.jsp|.gif|.jpg|.png))/(.*(?&lt;!.css|.js|.jsp|.gif|.jpg|.png))/(.*(?&lt;!.css|.js|.jsp|.gif|.jpg|.png))$</from>
        <to>/?game=$1&amp;sort=$2&amp;page=$3</to>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <from>/(.*(?&lt;!.css|.js|.jsp|.gif|.jpg|.png))/(.*(?&lt;!.css|.js|.jsp|.gif|.jpg|.png))$</from>
        <to>/?game=$1&amp;sort=$2</to>
    </rule>

</urlrewrite>
```

Comment: I've added what I tried.

Comment: Are you accepting user commands and trying to avoid malicious input (e.g. something that would either reveal all files or remove them)?

Comment: If you want to match *any* string with a `.` in it, `.*[.].*` is your friend.

Comment: this is all information i can give i think. if you need anymore let me know

Comment: You want the filenames but not the extension?

Comment: it is supposed to sort out anything that is between https://domain/foo/foo/1
to https://domain/?id=foo&secondid=foo&third=1

but file names should not get transformed.
so as soon as it is requesting https://domain/foo.gif
it should not redirect

Comment: Ahh! Letting us know that this is for the Tuckey urlrewrite filter is very helpful -- there's actually a StackOverflow tag for it; presumably its author is active in that tag, and would know definitively which regex syntax it uses. (Also, anyone curious enough to RTFS could [find it on github](https://github.com/paultuckey/urlrewritefilter/tree/master/src/main/java/org/tuckey/web/filters/urlrewrite)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of matching `.*` (zero or more of anything), match `[^.]*` (zero-or-more of anything except a period).

Thus:

```
<rule>
    <from>/vote/([^.]*)$</from>
    <to>/vote.jsp?id=$1</to>
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped